# CSS Google font-face not working on Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm trying to use Google Fonts without the external link to the css and i just copy and past the rule son my css like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTRampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

but Safari doesn't seems to get it...

Comment: Does it work if you test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rx40bgqk/) ?

Comment: nope it doesn't, i tried both my laptop & my ipad, not working

Comment: so some issue with safari , because it is working in FF and Chrome

Comment: woff2 not recognized by Safari, i'm using woff instead...

Answer (score 0):

ok i found the solution myself

woff2 is not compatible with Safari so i used

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTaRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have newly joined stackoverflow so not sure on the correct way to answer.

I was also facing a similar issue and seeing that safari is not downloading woff2 format files if mentioned in below format.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTRampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
```

}

But, if i add latin-ext subset files also in woff2 format then googleapis is internally downloading woff format. This has resolved the issue for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: " if i add latin-ext subset files also in woff2 format" do you mind elaborating on this - as this is your actual answer, but it is not described

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using only a single variant, the italic of Zilla Slab, Chrome display the italic version with out problem, but Safari required me to explicitly declare font-style:italic; before it would display correctly...

font-family: 'Zilla Slab', sans-serif; 
font-weight:400; 
font-style:italic;